# Fetching Public Profiles of any facebook user

Tags: r, facebook-graph-api, rfacebook

Is there a way to get the public profile data ( Name, age, Gender) for any facebook user. I know Previously we can just use this - `http://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID?fields=id,name,gender,link,picture&type=large`

But Now they have changed their API. Is it still possible?

I would like to do it in R and use rfacebook !  Any idea experts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way, for privacy reasons. You can only get data of a user by authorizing that user with the correct permissions. `name`, `age` and `gender` are available with basic permissions.

They changed it with v2.0 of the Graph API (April 30, 2014).

Comment: you are welcome. please dont forget to accept my answer ;)